# Are there any Q&A plugins / libraries written for / developed in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, osqa

Or failing that, any tutorials or guides as to how to create your own?

I have tried to read other implementations (osQA, etc), but each seems very different from the other, and I am having a tough time understanding the architecture / best practices.

Comment: A Q&A wouldn't be a plugin or library, it's an entire application on its own.

Comment: @Madmartigan Now that I think about it, I agree. I was thinking more in terms of my own requirement, which is to integrate it with something else. I used the word "plugin" very loosely, having just discovered CI after a lot of headaches with WP.

Comment: I still think you may have the wrong idea: Wordpress is a full-solution content management system. Codeigniter is a PHP framework to help you write your own applications, such as a content management system. Wordpress == does everything for you, CI == you do it yourself. Apologies if you're well aware of this.

Comment: @Madmartigan thanks, but I do know that. I am new to the web-dev world, which is why I was using WP earlier (too tempting to not use it... a lot of the core functionality is taken care of OOB in WP). But there is quite a bit of custom development (app) that is needed, which is where WP gave me headaches, and why I looked elsewhere, and found CI :) 
The QnA is around 10% of the whole app, so I cannot really use a WP solution for this.
Since I am still new, I'm trying to learn the right way of doing things. And I figure the best way to learn is to see some good code by others :)

Answer (score 1):

There are no libraries or plugins that i know of. Possibly a lot of Q&A programs have API's. You could use those to integrate a Q&A in your app.

There is this example such an app made in CI.
http://kroud.co/
Maybe the owner can help you?

That being said.
*A better place to start is to outline for yourself what you want from your Q&A.* In terms of features, goals, etc..
Right now that is not very clear to me.

You can make a lot of things in CI and there won't be a library or tutorial for each of those things!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress or similar is probably best for this - with loads of Q&A / Forum type themes written for it. Also Wordpress and Codigniter can work nicely together.

Heres some examples:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/q-and-a/

http://themeforest.net/item/instant-qa/92361

http://themeforest.net/item/sofa-qanda-knowledge-base-wp-theme/180802

http://faq-tastic.com/faqtastic-lite-free/